# How to enclose all cells with quotation marks?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a 502 entry column and I want to enclose each entry with quotes around each entry.

Example:

```
www.google.com -> "www.google.com"
www.twitch.tv -> "www.twitch.tv"
www.bbc.com -> "www.bbc.com"
```

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Comment: As much as I appreciate your help. If I knew the details on how to solve the said problem, the problem wouldn't be a "problem". That's exactly why I came here - looking for answers and solutions. I am pretty clear with what I asked for. I want my entries enclosed in quotes. Your solution solves my problem, so if you want to add it as a post I'll accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following

```
=REGEXREPLACE(P2,"(.*)","""$1")
```

[image]

Or for the whole range

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(P2:P="",,REGEXREPLACE(P2:P,"(.*)","""$1")))
```

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)